# Display actual cell value instead of #NAME?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a simple CSV file that I opened in Excel. There are some values like this:

```
=NAT
=NO FAULT
=NY
```

They are being displayed as `#NAME?` and I need the actual values displayed. I have tried:

- Changing the cell formatting to Text
- Formatting a new column as Text and pasting in
- Re-pasting over top the same values

Nothing has worked, it still gets displayed as `#NAME?`. How can I display the actual value?

Comment: Did you try the Data Import Wizard and import every column as text?

Answer (score 1):

You have to escpape the `=` char by adding `'` at the beginning, within Excel, not into the csv in text mode.

```
'=NAT
'=NO FAULT
'=NY
```

To apply everywhere in the worksheet you can use the `search and replace` feature :

```
Search = 
Replace by '=
replace all
```

---

**Edit** (as suggested by [**Jerry**](https://superuser.com/users/219090/jerry), thanks to him) : you can use the `data import` feature.

- Create a new empty worksheet
- Go to `Datas`
- Choose `From text`
- Choose your `txt/csv` file and click `import`
- Step 1 : keep default settings then `Next`
- Step 2 : keep default settings then `Next`
- Step 3 : choose `text` then `Finish`

(Sorry, maybe some traduction are bad, as i am French my Excel uses French language...)

Comment: Is there any way I can fix the display without editing cells?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: @JBurace Well, you don't have to if you use the Data Import Wizard correctly...

Comment: @Jerry: i took the liberty to edit my answer with your proposition. In case it is a problem or if you want to make your own answer i will delete my edit. Cheers

Comment: @user2196728 No problem, you can keep your answer :) Was just a bit annoyed that OP didn't answer my question earlier while obviously being around ^^;